# please tell me where i made error in this jsp program

Tags: java, debugging, jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%-- <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" %> --%>
<%
int iLf = 10;
char cLf = (char)iLf;
File outputFile = new File(generate.xml);
outputFile.createNewFile();
FileWriter outfile = new FileWriter(outputFile);
outfile.write(" <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> "+cLf);
outfile.write(" <playlist version='1' xmlns = 'http://xspf.org/ns/0/' > " +cLf);
outfile.write(" <title>My Band Rocks Your Socks</title> "+cLf); 
outfile.write("<trackList>"+cLf); 
%>
 <%! String[] sports; %>
 <%
    sports = request.getParameterValues("sports");
    if (sports != null)
    { 
         for (int i = 0; i < sports.length; i++)
         { 
              // outfile.writeln (sports[i]); 
              String total=sports[i];
              String[] sa=total.split("[,]");
              // String[] sub=new String();
              outfile.write("<track>"+cLf);
              for (int j=0;j<sa.length;j++)
              {
                // outfile.writeln(sa[j]);
                // outfile.writeln("sa["+j+"]="+sa[j]);
                if( j == 0)
                {
                     outfile.write("<location>" + sa[0] +"</location>"+cLf); 
                }
                else if (j == 1)
                     {
                        outfile.write("<image>" + sa[1] +"</image>"+cLf); 
                     }
                     else if( j==2)
                          {
                            outfile.write("<title>" + sa[2] +"</title>"+cLf);
                          }

               }// end of inner for loop()       
               outfile.write("</track>"+cLf);
         //outfile.writeln();
      }// end of outer for()
    } 
    //else outfile.writeln ("<b>none<b>");

  outfile.write(" </trackList> "+cLf);
  outfile.write(" </playlist> "+cLf);
  outfile.close();

  %>
```

### The exception thrown is

```
An error occurred at line: 7 in the jsp file: /sports3.jsp
generate.xml cannot be resolved to a type
4: <%
5: int iLf = 10;
6: char cLf = (char)iLf;
7: File outputFile = new File(generate.xml);
8: outputFile.createNewFile();
9: FileWriter outfile = new FileWriter(outputFile);
10: outfile.write(" <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> "+cLf);
```

---

please tell me how to rectify.

Comment: Edit the question and reformat the source code. More precisely, indent 4 characters.

Comment: Or select the entire code and click on the double quote icon.

Comment: Might I suggest moving this code out of a JSP, and into a servlet?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the culprit was

```
File outputFile = new File( generate.xml );
```

I suspect you probably want to wrap that string in quote marks (""), otherwise it'll be treated as an identifier, which the runtime won't know anything about.

Answer (score 1):

```
File outputFile = new File(generate.xml);
```

I guess generate.xml should be within double quotes, atleast that's my two cents.

Seriously, please format your code so that it appears better, otherwise its too tough to read.

Answer (score 1):

wow this is just unreadable !

the guilty line is

```
File outputFile = new File(generate.xml);
```

assuming generate.xml is the file name, you need to quote it as it is a String

```
File outputFile = new File("generate.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

generate.xml needs to be in quotes.  It doesn't see it as a string, it thinks you mean there's an object called "generate" with an "xml" property.